# Insert unique auto-increment ID on python to sql?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'd like to insert an Order_ID to make each row unique using python and pyodbc to SQL Server.

Currently, my code is:

```
name = input("Your name")

def connectiontoSQL(order_id,name):
    query = f'''\
        insert into order (Order_ID, Name)
        values('{order_id}','{name}')'''
    return (execute_query_commit(conn,query))
```

If my table in SQL database is empty and I'd like it to add a order_ID by 1 every time I execute,

How should I code order_id in Python such that it will automatically create the first order_ID as OD001, and if I execute another time, it would create OD002?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most products have such identity/sequence/etc functionality.)

Comment: BTW, switch to regular integer id's instead. So much easier to handle.

Comment: Hi, I'm quite new to this. I'm currently using SQL server. How should I code it in python then?

Comment: I'd let SQL Server handle this.

Comment: I can only do it by integer ID, how can I add the "OD00" in front instead of just the number "1" ?

Comment: What's wrong with the number 1? As I've already said, use plain integers, so much easier for you to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a INT Identity column as your primary key and add a computed column that has the order number that you display in your application.

```
create table Orders
(
[OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderNumber] as  'OD'+ right( '00000' + cast(OrderId as varchar(6)) , 6) ,
[OrderDate] date,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderId] ASC
)
)
```